# Strange behavior of `copyfile` regarding symlinks on Linux and macOS

Tags: linux, macos, matlab

Consider the following function.

```matlab
%test_copyfile.m

function test_copyfile()

system('rm -rf folder*; mkdir folder1; cd folder1; touch a b c d e f g; ln -s d dlink; rm d; cd ..');

success = copyfile('folder1','folder2');
assert(success);

fprintf('\nfolder1:\n');
dir('folder1')

fprintf('\nfolder2:\n');
dir('folder2')

assert(isequal({dir('folder1').name}, {dir('folder2').name}));

return
```

Running it in MATLAB R2023b on Ubuntu 22.04 or macOS 13 (Intel chip), I got the following result.

```
folder1:
  
.      ..     a      b      c      dlink  e      f      g      
  
  
folder2:
  
.   ..  b   f   
  
Error using assert
Assertion failed.
Error in test_copyfile (line 14)
assert(isequal({dir('folder1').name}, {dir('folder2').name}));
```

The test has been conducted on a few machines. It seems that the content of folder2 is not deterministic. Sometimes, it may be

```
folder2:
  
.   ..  a   g
```

or

```
folder2:
  
.   ..
```

But I have not recognized the pattern.

Is this expected?

Comment: This looks whacky. Obviously the copy operation was not successful, it should return `false`. But the order of files in a directory not being deterministic is expected. It probably reads the list of file names, and doesn’t sort the list in any way before copying. Why would you sort the list first? That makes sense. And when it gets to `dlink` it fails because it tries to resolve the link. But it should return a `false` when failing. You should report this bug to MathWorks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the response from MathWorks support.

"
Please be assured that this has been confirmed as a bug and is currently under thorough investigation by our development team. In the meantime, I have taken the initiative to attach your contact information to the relevant internal request. This ensures that you will be promptly notified when the bug is resolved in future releases.
"